# Get the keywords from positive and negative reviews

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have trained a classifier algorithm on a sentiment analysis model which classifies the reviews scraped off Amazon as Positive or Negative. Now for each class, I want to get the keywords from the review i.e. reason for the positive or negative review.

For example if I have a review "the quality of the shirt is the worst!". I want to get the keyword as "quality". Similarly "Really liked the fitting of the shirt" should return "fitting" as the keyword.

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: You could try to look into something like SHAP values to which features contribute to the model predicting a positive or negative sentiment.

Comment: Yes but I need to do this locally (i.e. for single prediction) as well as global (i.e. for the whole train and test data). I don't think SHAP can do this locally AFAIK.

Comment: If I am not mistaken SHAP values should be able to do both, see for example the [NLP example](https://github.com/slundberg/shap#natural-language-example-transformers) from the python `shap` package.

Comment: I checked your link and read some other articles and the link you mentioned uses transformers. Unfortunately i do not have access to a GPU and so cannot use Shap. I can use Shap for machine learning but due to lack of GPU cannot use it for NLP and DL.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the issue, the `shap` package is completely independing on whether you are using transformers or another model and are using a CPU or GPU for your computations. See for example [their documatation](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/tabular_examples/linear_models/Sentiment%20Analysis%20with%20Logistic%20Regression.html) where they use a logistic regression model for sentiment analysis.

Comment: I would expect that shap on the model would produce "worst", "liked" as leading to a negative and positive prediction in the examples respectively, rather than "quality", "fitting". I think you'd end up needing some sentence structure understanding or entity recognition to get what you want?  I don't know whether the answers address this difference or not...

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use integrated gradients to get an attribution for each word in a review and add them up over all reviews. Then you know for each word whether it let to a positive or negative review.

This is a [practical use case on how to use integrated gradients](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/integrated-gradients-nlp).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at keybert https://github.com/MaartenGr/KeyBERT which extract keywords